# Reset all filters at once

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a sidebar on my site that has 8 options to filter cars by. Each of the parameters is made in the form of a drop-down list. Parameters are made in various styles - calendar, checkbox, taginput, on/off button.

When the user wants to reset all filters, it is inconvenient for him to return everything to its original position. I would like to add a button that will bring the sidebar to its original position.

I added a very simplified code. Here I create a sidebar, and I prescribe each component (filter) in it.

```
    export default function FiltersSideBar({className}) {
    return (
        <CardContent className={className}>
            <Table>
                <TableBody>

                    <TableRow>
                        <TableCell>
                            <Filter1/>
                        </TableCell>
                    </TableRow>

                    <TableRow>
                        <TableCell>
                            <Filter2/>
                        </TableCell>
                    </TableRow>

                    <TableRow>
                        <TableCell>
                            <Filter3/>
                        </TableCell>
                    </TableRow>

                    <button>Reset All Filters</button>

                </TableBody>
            </Table>
        </CardContent>
    );
}
```

Is there any easy way to reset all filters and reset the sidebar?

Comment: This maybe a good place to move the filter logic to the parent component or pass a prop to each filter that causes a reset.  Add a Filter component code if you need more direction. Another option is to move the filter options to a useContext and you can clear it with the button more easily.

Comment: Control you filters using `state`. Your state should be an object. After changing each parameter, change relative item in the state and vice versa. When reset button is clicked, change state items to default values.

Comment: Could you please, provide a codesandbox with an example of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you don't need to set two files of the same component, `FilterDateTime.js`, they are the same component, and you can use it with different props values. this is the main concept of `components`.

About the filters, each filter should have a `state` control it as `filterDateTimeOpen` which control if the date input is opened or not, and `time` state which control the start and end date of the filter.

The benefit of the state is it is only updated by `setState` function. and then update the UI, Also state re-initialize to default state when the component unmount.

So, to reset the filters, you need to `setState` for each `state` that controls each filter.

Please have a look at this.

https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-mayer-6h28sy

Comment: Checkbox is controlled by `true/false` state, Please check, https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-meadow-drkccz

Comment: Can this be done at the component level? Since at the moment it turns out that I need to take out the code in App.js

Comment: It can but the state will reset when you close the sidebar ( the same old issue ).

Comment: Okay, then don't do it))

Comment: I'm having difficulty with this solution. The fact is that when I press the "Reset All" button, the filters are reset correctly, but in order for them to be applied (and the data to be displayed in its original form), I need to sequentially press this button. Tell me what could be the problem?

Comment: @Paul, I'm sorry, I didn't get what is the problem?

Comment: The sample code I give on the codecandbox does not contain the data I want to filter.  But I do have data that I get from the database. When I put several filters, the data is filtered, and when I press the "Reset all" button, they are reset one by one, but not all together

Comment: No, it should reset all together as I implemented in the codesandbox, you should reset all the states of the filters inside the reset button click method.

Comment: Sorry, yes , it's work,

Comment: Please tell me this question: since I have a lot of filters, my App.js is very cumbersome. Can I somehow move these defining parameters to another file or something else?

Comment: I suggest you use `Context`, it's the best solution for this case, for more resources https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

Comment: I spent a lot of time yesterday studying the context, but I never managed to apply it in the code. Could you show me how to do it, at least on the example of one component?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't want to use context or redux, you'd have to pull the state up to your FiltersSidebar (i.e. instead of each component handling it's own 'filter value', you keep track of all of that in the parent FiltersSidebar).

So something like:

```
export default function FiltersSideBar({className}) {

    const [filter1Value, setFilter1Value] = useState();
    const [filter2Value, setFilter2Value] = useState();
    const [filter3Value, setFilter3Value] = useState();

    const onResetAll = () => {
      setFilter1Value(null);
      setFilter2Value(null);
      setFilter3Value(null);
    }

    return (
        <CardContent className={className}>
            <Table>
                <TableBody>

                    <TableRow>
                        <TableCell>
                            <Filter1 value={filter1Value}/>
                        </TableCell>
                    </TableRow>

                    <TableRow>
                        <TableCell>
                            <Filter2 value={filter2Value}/>
                        </TableCell>
                    </TableRow>

                    <TableRow>
                        <TableCell>
                            <Filter3 value={filter3Value}/>
                        </TableCell>
                    </TableRow>

                    <button onClick={onResetAll}>Reset All Filters</button>

                </TableBody>
            </Table>
        </CardContent>
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice, unfortunately this option does not work

Comment: Can you share why this wouldn't work for you?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a object with the default filter state, and make a functionality that reset the filters wherever you want, so, you can do the following:

```js
// Declare a object with your filters
const defaultFilterState = {
  filter1: [],
  filter2: [],
  filter3: [],
  filter4: [],
};

export default function FiltersSideBar({ className }) {
  // declare state
  const [filters, setFilters] = useState(defaultFilterState);

  // Reset all filters
  const resetFilters = () => setFilters(defaultFilterState);

  return (
    <CardContent className={className}>
      <Table>
        <TableBody>
          <TableRow>
            <TableCell>
              <Filter1 value={filters.filter1} />
            </TableCell>
          </TableRow>

          <TableRow>
            <TableCell>
              <Filter2 value={filters.filter2} />
            </TableCell>
          </TableRow>

          <TableRow>
            <TableCell>
              <Filter3 value={filters.filter3} />
            </TableCell>
          </TableRow>

          <TableRow>
            <TableCell>
              <Filter4 value={filters.filter4} />
            </TableCell>
          </TableRow>

          <button onClick={resetFilters}>Reset All Filters</button>
        </TableBody>
      </Table>
    </CardContent>
  );
}
```